# How can I test a request with a literal given querystring?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, get, query-string

For testing a given API I have to test a request with an exact querystring, because the whole querystring is hashed together with a shared secret for security, like

```
inject?a=1&b[a]=2&b[b]=3&d=4&sign=76c8abec496a5e6c8a51c57e231e3a62612aeff0
```

I can only see a way to give parameters as a hash, which does not ensure the order (at least not if it's a nested hash):

```
test "right signature injects" do
  get :inject, a:1 , b: {a:2, b:3}, d: 4, sign: '76c8abec496a5e6c8a51c57e231e3a62612aeff0'
  assert_response :success
end
```

How can I test a get request with an exact query string?

Answer (score 0):

Why does the order make a difference? If you are passing GET variables surely order doesn't matter?
I can't see any reason why your test shouldn't do what you need unless there is something in the controller that responds to this request.

Comment: The querystring until the &sign= is hashed. only when the hash is correct an action shall be taken by the controller. Changing the order of the parameters changes the hash.

Comment: I am guessing you need the sign variable to decode the hash? If it needs to be hashed why aren't you hashing it in your test? Should it be something like: get :inject, hash:xyz, sign: abc

Comment: The sender of the request calculates sign as
    sha1("a=1&b[a]=2&b[b]=3&d=4" + secret)
and adds it as the last item to the querystring.
To verify, I have to calculate the md5 on the exact querystring in its sent order.